# How to fetch results from two tables using single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to fetch two different collumn value from two different tables.first i want to fetch message and userid from message table and then the message_from is used to fetch the details of that user from user table and display both message and user details.How to do that from a single query Here is my try

```
$select_my_message = mysql_query("select firstname from user where user_no = (select message_from, message_body from messages where message_to = '$userno')"); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select_my_message))
{
    echo $row['message_from'];
    echo $row['message_body'];
    echo $row['firstname'];
}
```

Comment: This is called a "join" and is a fundamental concept in SQL and relational databases.

Comment: i use join but nothing works can u please tell me how to do that i am using innerjoin

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data.  You can also try setting up a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: You cannot select multiple column in sub-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `INNER JOIN` u can get the result.

```
SELECT a.firstname,
       b.message_from,
       b.message_body
FROM   USER a
       JOIN messages b
         ON a.user_no = b.message_to
WHERE  b.message_to = '$userno'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the column 'user_no' is also in table messages you can do something like:

select  firstname
from user
where user_no in ( select user_no
                   from messages
                   where message_to = ‘$userno’)

Comment: no user_no is not in the message_table but it is on the user_table i fetch message_from from messages table and uses that id to fetch the user details from user table